# How to stop tableview cells from glitching and flickering image when scrolling in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, uitableview

I have a tableview that displays data from Firebase. It displays fine in the tableview but when scrolling begins, the table starts glitching or having the cells image and text reload and flicker which is very ugly. Help! Here's my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell
func downloadPicture(finished: () -> Void) {
            cell.profilePicture.image = nil
                if let imageUrlString = self.payments[indexPath.row].picture,
                       let imageUrl = URL(string: imageUrlString) {
                        do {
                            let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
                            cell.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                            cell.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profilePicture.frame.size.width / 2
                            cell.profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true
                            cell.profilePicture.alpha = 1
                        }
                        catch {
                            print("Error fetching image - \(error)")
                    }
            }
            finished()
    }
    downloadPicture {
        print("success")
}
cell.amountLabel.text = "$\(self.payments[indexPath.row].amount ?? "")"
cell.detailsLabel.text = self.payments[indexPath.row].amount ?? ""
return cell
```

}

Comment: Reloading content on scroll is expected and intended (even necessary) behavior. Rather than asking for stopping it I would ask for fixing the *glitching*.

Comment: Ok, and it seems like reloading would be a good thing but this displays different cell information for a brief second before loading which seems counter-intuitive and it pauses/glitches the scrolling UI.

Comment: Thanks, how do you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply go with [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) An asynchronous image downloader with cache management and efficient to use.

**i.e.** :

```
import SDWebImage

yourImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "yourImageURLFromFirebase.jpg"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Answer (score 1):

@Lukeksaunders just go to GitHub [Kinfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher). This library contains all functionality you want.

```
import Kingfisher
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/image.png")
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

This library cache your images

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell
    if let imageUrlString = self.payments[indexPath.row].picture,
       let imageUrl = URL(string: imageUrlString) {
        cell.profilePicture.kf.setImage(with: imageUrl)
    }
    cell.amountLabel.text = "$\(self.payments[indexPath.row].amount ?? "")"
    cell.detailsLabel.text = self.payments[indexPath.row].amount ?? ""
    return cell
}
```